# VBA click event on array of combo boxes

Tags: vba, excel

Hey all I have the following VBA code that allows me to have a click event on a dynamically created comboboxes and textboxes onto the userform.

userform:

```
Option Explicit

Dim comboboxBoxColct  As New Collection

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
Dim comboboxEvent           As Class1
Dim controller(100)         As Object

   '..lots more code within here
   With controller(i)
      .Name = "cmdBOM" & i
      .Top = 10
      .ForeColor = vbBlack
      .Height = 15
      .FontName = "Times New Roman"
      .FontSize = 6
      .AutoSize = False
      .Caption = "Add New Row"
      .BackColor = RGB(204, 255, 201)
      .TabStop = True
      .TabIndex = i
   End With

   Set comboboxEvent = New Class1
   Set comboboxEvent.comboboxBox = controller(i)
   comboboxBoxColct.Add comboboxEvent
End Sub
```

Class1:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents comboboxBox As MSForms.ComboBox

Sub SetCombobox(ctl As MSForms.ComboBox)
    Set comboboxBox = ctl
End Sub

Private Sub comboboxBox_Click()
    If comboboxBox.ListIndex > -1 Then
        MsgBox "You clicked on " & comboboxBox.Name & vbLf & _
               "The value is " & comboboxBox.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

The above code **works just fine**. However, once I click on the combo box and select something, the msgbox comes up saying:

> You clicked on
>
> The value is

There are no values for **.Name** or **.Value** when looking at the **_Click()** event and I'm not sure why that is? I place a break point on **Set comboboxBox = ctl** and it just seems to come up all the time with **""**.

[image]

What can I do in order to get this to work?

Comment: Have you tried the `Change` event?

Comment: the popup only show when i select a value in the dropdown.

Comment: Right, so try putting the code on the `Change` event instead of the `Click` event which also fires when you initially drop down the combobox.

Comment: Still the same result. Could it be because its an array and its not saving each combobox value except for the last one in line?

Comment: I noticed that your `Sub SetCombobox` is not what you call here: `Set comboboxEvent.comboboxBox`, so I'm not sure how that `SetCombobox` sub is being called. Have you checked the locals window to verify that the ctl variable is not "Nothing"? Or checked the call stack at the break point, to see when the `SetCombobox` got called?